# End value is null when moving event in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using `FullCalendar 4.3.1` and when I move one task (event) from one day to another I'm receiving the `end` field to null.

I initialize the calendar like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let calendarElement = document.getElementById('calendar');
    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      locale: 'es',
      plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek, timeGridDay'
      },
      defaultDate: '0000-00-00',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      select: function(data) {
        // Not relevant
      },
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [],
      eventRender: function(info) {
      },
      eventDrop: function(info) { <-- (1) 
        moveTask(info.event.id, info.event.start, info.event.end);
      },
      eventResize: function(info) {
        moveTask(info.event.id, info.event.start, info.event.end);
      },
      eventClick: function(info) {
         // Not relevant
       }
    });
    calendar.render();
    fillCalendar(); <- Custom method to fill the calendar
});
```

So, if I move one task from Wednesday to Tuesday, at **(1)** I get the `id`, the `start` field but then `end` field it's null.

Reading the [eventDrop docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop) it says that the `event` field it's an [eventObject](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) with `start` and `end`.

Also, I don't have `allDay` property. Because it may infer with the `end` value:

> Something date-parseable. When your event ends. If your event is
>   explicitly allDay, hour, minutes, seconds and milliseconds will be
>   ignored. If omitted, your events will appear to have the default
>   duration. See defaultAllDayEventDuration, defaultTimedEventDuration,
>   and forceEventDuration for more info.
>
> Note: This value is exclusive. For example, if you have an all-day
>   event that has an end of 2018-09-03, then it will span through
>   2018-09-02 and end before the start of 2018-09-03.

It's explained here: [Explanation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing)

And the events are filled from a DDBB where all events have a `start` and an `end` date like this. It's an array of dicts:

```
{'id': row['id'], 'title': row['title'], 'start': row['start'], 'end': row['end'], 'backgroundColor': row['color'], 'borderColor': row['color']}
```

So, what I'm doing wrong that causes get `end` to `null`?

Regards.

-- EDIT:

I've added a picture with the data which it's populated FullCalendar.

[image: Data debuger]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/MWgzaQN?&editable=true&editors=001. Are you sure your events definitely have valid "end" properties when you supply them to fullCalendar? We could do with seeing an actual example of the event object you're providing (rather than the code which generates it, which proves nothing to me since I don't have access to the data source).

Comment: Hi, @ADyson I've uploaded a screeshot. Regards.

Comment: Ok. In that case though you should not be getting the error you're seeing. As I've demonstrated, your code, when used with events which have valid end dates, does not cause the problem you've described. So unless you can provide a reproducible example (perhaps by forking my CodePen and changing the code/data so it will show the issue happening), it's unclear how we can really help you. There's nothing obviously wrong which would cause the stated problem.

Comment: P.S. Any particular reason you're using that strange and long-winded method of adding events when you could just use one of the standard approaches recommended by fullCalendar? e.g. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function. I think you're making more work and code for yourself than you need to, and not taking advantage of some of the useful features.

Comment: Hi, I'm retrieving the data from a SQlite database via GET request. I'll look to that methods to se if they solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would solve the problem in your question (since it's not reproducible, I can't say what _would_ solve it), I was just pointing out that your method is not the most efficient. If you are just making a simple GET request then https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed might make your code simpler - depending on your specific circumstances it could be as simple as writing `events: "http://yourURL.com",` with no further code required. Read that link and you'll see what's possible.

Comment: Thanks for that method, filling the calendar it's more easy that way but I'm still with the error. I'll try to dig more tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what was wrong with the events that I created to fill as an example. With events created by the calendar the 'end' propety is filled. The problem now it's that they can't be resized, I can only drag.